# Asp Checkbox OnCheckedChanged firing only when another control does postback

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap

I have a simple form with a gridview and one of the fields is a templateField

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="State" SortExpression="IsActive">
   <ItemTemplate>
       <asp:CheckBox runat="server" ClientIDMode="AutoID" ID="IsActive" AutoPostBack="true"    OnCheckedChanged="IsActive_CheckedChanged" Enabled="true"/>
   </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

I am setting ClientIDMode to AutoID to make each of the checkboxex unique.
I have found a solution to make my Checkbox looks like a switch using bootstrap
http://www.bootstrap-switch.org/

so I also have a js method to enable bootstrap

```
    function bootstrapSwitch() {
        var grid = document.getElementById("GridViewFeatures");

        var inputs = grid.getElementsByTagName("input");

        for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
            var str1 = "#";
            var str2 = inputs[i].id;
            var res = str1.concat(str2);
            $(res).bootstrapSwitch();
        }
```

and so I can see a nice bootstrap switch control.
However when I press the Checkbox OnCheckedChanged event does not fire.
I have placed a breakpoint inside of the handler and noticed, that when I press checkbox and then press another simple button

```
<asp:Button ID="ButtonRefresh" runat="server" Text="Refresh" OnClick="ButtonRefresh_Click" />
```

I am getting inside OnCheckedChanged, so it only fires when another control does a postback.
Tell me please, how can I fix it to be able to use bootstrap style and code behind logic at the same time.

Comment: Do you notice a postback?

Comment: @TimSchmelter What do you mean?

Comment: You have mentioned that the `OnCheckedChanged`-event is not triggered but you haven't mentioned if a postback happens at all. Have you set a breakpoint in `Page_Load`?

Comment: @TimSchmelter, I see, so no, nothing happens when I press CheckBox, only when I press the button I can see a postback and CheckBox event

Comment: So, @TimSchmelter, do you have any idea why this can happen?